# How to use "Sign In with Apple" with Apple JS

Tags: javascript, html, apple-sign-in

I would use "Sign In with Apple" in the web via Apple JS. The code example can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple

The question now is: what is the Client ID and where can I find it. I tested the identifier of the app id on https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list and I tested the identifier of the service id. If I click on the button and verify with Touch ID on my mac, I got the error "AUTH_ALERT_SIGN_UP_NOT_COMPLETED":

[image]

This is the used code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="sign-in-with-apple-button"> Sign In with Apple </button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            AppleID.auth.init({
                clientId : 'unknown',
                scope : 'email',
                redirectURI: 'https://mytld/test.php',
                state : 'DE'
            });

            const buttonElement = document.getElementById('sign-in-with-apple-button');
            buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
                AppleID.auth.signIn();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I got no request on test.php.

Comment: [The developer’s client identifier, as provided by WWDR. You *must* obtain a client identifier from *WWDR* before you can use Sign In with Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplejs/clientconfigi/3230948-clientid)

Comment: Yes, but where can I find this client identifier? In the documentation is no link or something.

Comment: State is not "DE" as in Delaware, but rather a custom "application state" that you can use to  mitigate CSRF. Check out this article: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Client ID is the "Identifier" of your [Service ID](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list/serviceId) that has "Sign In with Apple" enabled:

[image: Service ID Configuration]

Apple recommends you make it the following format on the [Register a Service ID screen](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/serviceId/add/):

> We recommend using a reverse-domain name style string (i.e., com.domainname.appname). It cannot contain an asterisk (*).

Comment: So it is not possible to implement "Sign In with Apple" without the developer membership?

Comment: Correct -- it is not possible to enable Sign In with Apple without an Apple Developer membership.

Comment: @Kaspars How did you configure the Sign In With Apple part? Where's that doc.  When I enter my domain name it just tells me it is invalid, and the instructions are weird as it says to download something but there is no download link.

Comment: Only Apple can call CLIENT ID on the API and call it Service Identifier on their side. That's mental.

Answer (score -1):

I had try  bundleId & clientId in the place of MyAppClientId but always getting error Invalid Client Id in Apple SingIn popup.

AppleID.auth.init({
clientId : MyAppClientId,
scope : "email",
redirectURI : "https://test.com",
state : "signin",
usePopup : true });

Is there any way when we can use clientId/bundleId in web apple login process

How can we configure on Web logo in place of Apple logo in login popup

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35470665)

Comment: I had added new Question for issue, Please add your suggestion 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77785000/how-to-show-custom-logo-in-place-of-apple-logo-sign-in-with-apple-with-apple