# "Incomplete registration" error using "Sign in with Apple"

Tags: ios, apple-id, sign-in-with-apple

I am attempting to submit a new iOS app to Apple that uses "Sign in with Apple" to authenticate users. In all my local testing, this works perfectly.

During Apple's review process, they ran into an error and provided this screenshot:
[image: Sign in with Apple modal with error text "未完成注册"]

Unfortunately, the error message is in Chinese, but Google Translate say it means "Incomplete registration".

The weird thing about this is that the error message is in place of where there should be a button. Here is how the screen looks when I try it:
[image: Sign in with Apple modal with button that says "continue with password"]

Does anyone know how to get into this state where there is an error instead of a button to continue with the sign-in process?

Is it possible that this is human-error on the part of the reviewer, and they for some reason don't have the Apple ID account setup correctly on the device?

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I am using Firebase authentication to handle the sign-in process. It appears from the screenshot that this occurs before any requests are made to the backend though.

---

**Update:**
I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442900/how-to-use-sign-in-with-apple-with-apple-js) that has a similar error message in English. It may be related to my issue, but I have been unable to reproduce this error by using an incorrect Bundle ID as the accepted answer suggests. I just wanted to add this info, as it may have some relevance.

I don't currently have a physical iOS device to test on. Is it possible that this error is only displayed on real devices or only when using a signed `.ipa`?

---

**Update - App was approved:**

I resubmitted my app for review and it was approved, so it seems that human-error or some glitch in Apple's process caused it to be rejected initially. Although my problem is solved, I still have no idea how the reviewer managed to get into the state displayed in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The "Sign-Up Not Completed"/未完成註冊 may be caused by using + signs instead of encoded spaces (%20) in the URL when you redirect to https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize

Source: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/122458

Comment: I forgot to update my question. I resubmitted my app, and it was approved. I didn't change any URLs, so I wouldn't think this would be the issue, unless Apple had some kind of glitch. I imagine it's possible that their reviewer's requests might go through some type of proxy to analyze requests or something, so its possible but hard to determine.