# How to show custom logo in place of Apple logo, "Sign In with Apple" with Apple JS

Tags: apple-sign-in, apple-login

In my Apple Developer account create a clientId & ServiceId. ServiceId is mapped with clientId. App is developed for IOS device & Web.

I am using serviceId  in for Web to showing  Apple SingIn consent popup.

```
AppleID.auth.init({ 
clientId : serviceId, 
cope : "email", 
redirectURI : "https://test.com", 
state : "signin", 
usePopup : true });
```

Upload our website logo in AppStore which is mapped with clientId.

In IOS device new logo is coming but In web login not getting our new logo, it's showing Apple logo.

How can we configure for on Web in place of Apple logo in login popup?